# Enterprise distribution of iOS applications

Tags: iphone, ios

Does anyone know what is the best way (if any) to distribute iOS applications to enterprise. Specifically, what I am looking to do is to send my app to a few businesses but not to others. I doubt anything like that exists, but still wondering...

thanks.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/support/ios/enterprise.html, https://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/

Comment: not what I Am looking for...I am looking to reply my application to another organizations. the apple developer enterprise program is meant for enterprise to develop for themselves as far as I understood it. thanks though.

Comment: It depends - you can also make an enterprise account for the company you're developing for or they make it and possibly sign an account-maintenance contract with you. There are some possibilities but true, not many.

Comment: but they won't be able to submit the app to the store under my application name, it would have to be a separate app, right?

Comment: Usually developer (you) is also the one who manages enterprise account(s). Maybe there are some better solutions, this one certainly isn't great.

Comment: heard there is also an option for enterprises to control which devices can be installed on their devices, that could also help me. do you know anything about that?

Comment: You probably mean which applications can be installed - i think i heard something about that - don't know for sure, but this is certainly not controlled vie enterprise account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I'm reading, you can't do what you're trying to do. You can't have a "private" sale of apps. You can register as a business if you have a Dun & Bradstreet number and then license the use of your app to other businesses. That is possible, but if Apple finds out they will revoke your license because the enterprise developer license is for in-house only.

The only legal solution is to have each business register an enterprise account and then set you up as the developer for their account. No legal way around that, sorry.

Comment: Thanks jonusx. I heard there is some B2B program where similar things can be done, so like, you can rebrand your app for other companies. know anything about that?

Comment: It didn't seem like that's what you were trying to do. The B2B program is great if you want to sell apps to another business. The thing is that you aren't selling the app itself, only one copy at a time. So if the business wants to use it for 1000 employees, they have to buy 1000 copies. Also, the minimum price for an app like that is 9.99 US so it would cost the company 10,000 US. So it is an option is the business is willing to buy the app like that.